# A very simple histogram with R?

Tags: r, plot, dataset, histogram, rstudio

I'm at very beginning with R programming. I'm using RStudio for an exam, and I have to represent graphically the results of some calculations on a dataset.
I have a structure like that:

[image]

and what I was thinking to do was make some histograms with the 3 values of the mean for each row, and the same for median and trimmed mean.

**First question:** Is this a correct way to represent this kind of data graphically? Or there are some better plot.

**Second question:** Could someone give me the code to draw a graph with on the x avis the 3 strings ("Lobby", "R & D","ROE") and on the y axis a scale of values ​​that includes the results, in order to have the histograms representing the differences in investment in lobbing, r & d and the roe obtained.

Hope I've been clear enough, if I haven't specified something relevant please ask me.

Comment: Problem is that if you put together in the same plot, numbers having so different scales like 0.0084 and 6, you cannot discern the first number from zero... e.g. try this:  barplot(t(as.matrix(yourDataFrame)),beside = TRUE) # replace yourDataFrame with the name of your data.frame

Answer (score 1):

Its sounds like you want to do the following. With your data in a csv call `bar.csv` having this format:

```
Dept    Mean    Median  Trimmed_Mean
Lobby   0.008   0.0018  0.0058
R & D   6.25    3.2     4.78
ROE     19.08   16.66   16.276
```

You can use `library(ggplot2)` and `library(reshape)` and the commands listed here

```
dat.m<-read.csv("bar.csv")
dat.m<-melt(dat.m,id.vars="Dept")

ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = Dept, y = value,fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')+
facet_wrap(~ Dept, ncol = 3,scales="free_y") #facet wrapped

ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = Dept, y = value,fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') 
#stacked bar
```

to display the graphs below:

[image: stacked facet]
[image: stacked bar]

As zhaoy says, a historgram works with raw data (usually) - and what you have is summary data. Also,  you could use `library(ggplot2)` to produce a boxplot summary graph like this (using `spray` data in the ggplot2 library):

```
library(ggplot2)
p<-qplot(spray,count,data=InsectSprays,geom='boxplot')
p<-p+stat_summary(fun.y=mean,shape=1,col='red',geom='point')
print(p)
```

Or simply using the standard `boxplot` command, with the same data, with added functionality to display the means:

```
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray")
means <- tapply(InsectSprays$count,InsectSprays$spray,mean)
points(means,col="red",pch=18)
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to question 1: The purpose of histograms is to display the density or frequency of continuous data. If you're trying to compare the mean / median / trimmed mean across the 3 categories in the row.name column, I suggest bar graphs. I'm not sure comparing mean / median / trimmed mean in a single graph is coherent to viewers, so it may be ideal to generate 3 bar graphs.

In response to question 2: If you aim to compare the 3 categories in the row.name column using multiple columns of data, I suggest a box-plot. I realize that the box-plot does not traditionally include the mean, but it is one of the best visualizations for comparing data across categories. Please see [r-bloggers.com/box-plot-with-r-tutorial](http://r-bloggers.com/box-plot-with-r-tutorial) for an example.

Comment: No my idea was: 3 different graph, one for mean, one for median and one for trimmed mean. In every single graph I compare values of lobby, r&d and roe. Btw thank you for your answer I will follow the tutorial and hope it will help me.