# How to do histograms of this row-column table in R ggplot?

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, statistics

I am trying to plot the descriptive variables in the first row by the following procedure. 
I also tried unsuccessfully with quoting the column/row names

1. rotate rows and columns in the CSV data for the correposding data structure (tall table) required in the thread [A very simple histogram with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25584792/54964) with `ggplot`
2. to plot histogram of events as `Absolute` variable XOR (`Average`, `Min`, `Max`)

   - If absolute value only, just draw absolute value in histogram.
   - If (average, min and max), just draw them in the histogram with whiskers (= **whisker plot**) where the limits of the whiskers are made by the min and max.

Data

1. initially, `data.csv`

   ```
   "Vars"    , "Sleep", "Awake", "REM", "Deep"
   "Absolute",        ,       , 5     , 7
   "Average" , 7      , 12    ,       ,
   "Min"     , 4      , 5     ,       , 
   "Max"     , 10     , 15    ,       ,
   ```
2. data after reshaping visually

   ```
               V1       V2       V3       V4
   Vars  Absolute Average  Min      Max     
   Sleep     <NA>        7        4       10
   Awake     <NA>       12        5       15
   REM          5     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
   Deep         7     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
   ```
3. data after reshaping for R

   ```
    data <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L), .Names = c("Vars", 
    "Sleep", "Awake", "REM", "Deep"), .Label = c(" 5", " 7", "Absolute"
    ), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA), .Names = c("Vars", 
    "Sleep", "Awake", "REM", "Deep"), .Label = c("12", " 7", "Average "
    ), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA), .Names = c("Vars", 
   "Sleep", "Awake", "REM", "Deep"), .Label = c(" 4", " 5", "Min     "
    ), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA), .Names = c("Vars", 
   "Sleep", "Awake", "REM", "Deep"), .Label = c("10", "15", "Max     "
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), row.names = c("Vars", 
   "Sleep", "Awake", "REM", "Deep"), class = "data.frame")
   ```

R code with debugging code

```
dat.m <- read.csv("data.csv")

# rotate rows and columns
dat.m <- as.data.frame(t(dat.m)) # https://stackoverflow.com/a/7342329/54964 Comment 42-

library("reshape2")
dat.m <- melt(dat.m, id.vars="Vars")

## Just plot values existing there correspondingly    
library("ggplot2")
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/25584792/54964
# TODO following
#ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = "Vars", y = value,fill=variable))
```

Error

```
Error: id variables not found in data: Vars
Execution halted
```

R: 3.3.3, 3.4.0 (backports)
OS: Debian 8.7
R reshape2, ggplot2, ... with `sessionInfo()` after loading the two packages

```
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.1.0  reshape2_1.4.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.3-2 scales_0.4.1     magrittr_1.5     plyr_1.8.4      
 [5] tools_3.3.3      gtable_0.2.0     Rcpp_0.12.10     stringi_1.1.5   
 [9] grid_3.3.3       stringr_1.2.0    munsell_0.4.3
```

### Testing HaberdashPI's [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44031194/54964)

Output in Fig. 1 where wrongly absolute value in `Sleep` and `Awake`. 
If `NA`, just set value to zero.

Fig. 1 HaberdashPI's proposal output not as expected

[image]

Data structure of `dat.m` before the transpose

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Absolute: Factor w/ 2 levels " 5"," 7": NA NA 1 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "Sleep" "Awake" "REM" "Deep"
 $ Average : Factor w/ 2 levels "12"," 7": 2 1 NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "Sleep" "Awake" "REM" "Deep"
 $ Min     : Factor w/ 2 levels " 4"," 5": 1 2 NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "Sleep" "Awake" "REM" "Deep"
 $ Max     : Factor w/ 2 levels "10","15": 1 2 NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "Sleep" "Awake" "REM" "Deep"
 $ Vars    : chr  "Sleep" "Awake" "REM" "Deep"
      Absolute Average  Min      Max       Vars
Sleep     <NA>        7        4       10 Sleep
Awake     <NA>       12        5       15 Awake
REM          5     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>   REM
Deep         7     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>  Deep
```

Data structure of `dat.m` after the transpose

```
'data.frame':   16 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Vars    : chr  "Sleep" "Awake" "REM" "Deep" ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 4 levels "Absolute","Average ",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ value   : chr  NA NA " 5" " 7" ...

    Vars variable value
1  Sleep Absolute  <NA>
2  Awake Absolute  <NA>
3    REM Absolute     5
4   Deep Absolute     7
5  Sleep Average      7
6  Awake Average     12
7    REM Average   <NA>
8   Deep Average   <NA>
9  Sleep Min          4
10 Awake Min          5
11   REM Min       <NA>
12  Deep Min       <NA>
13 Sleep Max         10
14 Awake Max         15
15   REM Max       <NA>
16  Deep Max       <NA>
```

### Testing akash87's [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44090815/54964)

Code

```
ds <- dat.m
str(ds)
ds
ds$variable
ds$variable %in% c("Min","Max")
```

Wrong output because all `False` in the end

```
 $ Vars    : chr  "Sleep" "Awake" "REM" "Deep" ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 4 levels "Absolute","Average ",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ value   : chr  NA NA " 5" " 7" ...
    Vars variable value
1  Sleep Absolute  <NA>
2  Awake Absolute  <NA>
3    REM Absolute     5
4   Deep Absolute     7
5  Sleep Average      7
6  Awake Average     12
7    REM Average   <NA>
8   Deep Average   <NA>
9  Sleep Min          4
10 Awake Min          5
11   REM Min       <NA>
12  Deep Min       <NA>
13 Sleep Max         10
14 Awake Max         15
15   REM Max       <NA>
16  Deep Max       <NA>
[1] "hello 3"
 [1] Absolute Absolute Absolute Absolute Average  Average  Average  Average 
 [9] Min      Min      Min      Min      Max      Max      Max      Max     
Levels: Absolute Average  Min      Max     
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So doing `ds[ds$variable %in% c("Min","Max"), ]` will given `False` output because error-carried-forward.

### Testing Uwe's [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44131736/54964)

Code with explicit `data.table::dcast` and two times `data.table::melt`. Printing out `sessionInfo()` just before `molten <- ...`. Note `library(ggplot2)` is not loaded yet because the error comes from the line `molten <- ...`.

```
$ Rscript test111.r 
    Vars "Average" "Max" "Min" Absolute
1: Sleep         7    10     4       NA
2: Awake        12    15     5       NA
3:   REM        NA    NA    NA        5
4:  Deep        NA    NA    NA        7
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.12.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.10.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 methods_3.4.0 
Error in melt.data.table(transposed, measure.vars = c("Absolute", "Average")) : 
  One or more values in 'measure.vars' is invalid.
Calls: <Anonymous> -> melt.data.table
Execution halted
```

### Testing Uwe's proposal with test code 2

Code

```
molten <- structure(list(Vars = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), class = "factor", .Label = c("V1", "V2")), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), class = "factor", .Label = c("ave", "ave_max", "lepo")), value = c(7L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("Vars", "variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

print(molten)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(molten, aes(x = Vars, y = value, fill = variable, ymin = lepo, ymax = ave_max)) + 
  geom_col() + geom_errorbar(width = 0.2)
```

Output

```
  Vars variable value
1   V1      ave     7
2   V2      ave     8
3   V1  ave_max    10
4   V2  ave_max    10
5   V1     lepo     4
6   V2     lepo     4
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'lepo' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... by_layer -> f -> <Anonymous> -> f -> lapply -> FUN -> FUN
Execution halted
```

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Comment: @TheBiro I defined more carefully the desired output in the body.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what I did that was wrong for the explanation you are looking for. What are you expecting?

Comment: @akash87 Nothing wrong. I am testing your proposal. It is the best so far.

Comment: What improvements could be made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you used "Vars" with a quote instead of simple Vars in the ggplot aes function. Also, the header of your data set is messed up. The Absolute, Average, ... should be the column names of the data set, not the values themselves. That's why you get the error from melt function.

Given your data set, here is my attempt:

```
#Data
data = cbind.data.frame(c("Sleep", "Awake", "REM", "Deep"),
                        c(NA, NA, 5, 7),
                        c(7, 12, NA, NA),
                        c(4, 5, NA, NA),
                        c(10, 15, NA, NA))
colnames(data) = c("Vars", "Absolute", "Average", "Min", "Max")

#reshape
dat.m <- melt(data, id.vars="Vars")
#Stacked plot
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = Vars, y = value)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), stat = "identity")
```

This will produce:

[image: stacked bar]

```
#Or multiple bars
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = Vars, y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), stat = "identity", position="dodge")
```

[image: nonstacked]

```
#Or separated by Vars
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = Vars, y = value)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), stat = "identity", position="dodge") + facet_wrap( ~ Vars, scales="free")
```

[image: separatedbyvar]

I am adding another graph to the answer. This collaborates @Uwe answer.

```
#data
data <- structure(list(Vars = structure(1:2, class = "factor", .Label = c("V1", "V2")), ave = c(7L, 8L), ave_max = c(10L, 10L), lepo = c(4L, 4L)), .Names = c("Vars", "ave", "ave_max", "lepo"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), sorted = "Vars")
#Melt
library(data.table)
mo = data.table::melt(data, measure.vars = c("ave"))
ggplot(mo, aes(x = Vars, y = value, fill = variable, ymin = lepo, ymax = ave_max)) + geom_col() + geom_errorbar(width = 0.2)
```

This will produce:

[image]

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 I can't add pictures here, but it is very simple. Just replace dat.m with molten in the ggplot. For example, ggplot(molten, aes(x = Vars, y = value)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), stat = "identity", position="dodge") .

Comment: Great, glad I can help.

Comment: It produced the error because if you check your molten data set, you do not have the variable (column name) called 'lepo'. To do the graph:
mo = data.table::melt(data, measure.vars = c("Absolute", "Average"))
ggplot(mo, aes(Vars, value, fill = variable, ymin = Min, ymax = Max)) + 
 geom_col() + geom_errorbar(width = 0.2)

Comment: `mo = data.table::melt(data, measure.vars = c("Absolute", "Average"))`
`ggplot(mo, aes(Vars, value, fill = variable, ymin = Min, ymax = Max)) +  geom_col() + geom_errorbar(width = 0.2)`

Comment: Is this what you want?
`mo = data.table::melt(data, measure.vars = c("ave"))`
`ggplot(mo, aes(x = Vars, y = value, ymin = lepo, ymax = ave_max, fill = Vars)) + geom_col() + geom_errorbar(width = 0.2)
            `

Comment: In the last graph, I would add `ggplot(mo, aes(x = Vars, y = value, fill = variable, ymin = lepo, ymax = ave_max)) + geom_col() + geom_errorbar(width = 0.2)` because the values are about averages.

Comment: I award this answer the bounty because he understands the initial data management and see the big picture here and shows how to visualise different types of the plots i.e. visualises the situation very well. Congratulations! - - Please, remove some of your comments to keep your answer nice and clean.

Answer (score 3):

Your basic problem, is that your column and row names have been messed up when you call `dat.m <- as.data.frame(t(dat.m))`. That is not really the right way to rearrange your data.

Your terminology is a little confusing (do your really mean [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram)?), so I'm not sure if this is what you want, but I believe to solve the immediate problem you're having, you can do this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

dat.m <- read.csv("data.csv")

m <- t(dat.m)
dat.m <- data.frame(m[2:nrow(m),])
names(dat.m) <- m[1,]
dat.m$Vars <- rownames(m)[2:nrow(m)]

dat.m <- melt(dat.m, id.vars="Vars")
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = Vars, y = value,fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Here's the output I get:[image]

What I've done here is manually renamed the column names (`names(data.m) <- etc...`) and inserted a new column called `Vars`, because you need those names as a column of `dat.m`, not a set of row names, to refer to them in `melt` (which is why you get the error you're getting about not being able to find `Vars`). It isn't elegant, but it gets the job done.

It looks like you're making a lot more work for yourself than you may need. It appears that you have already collected a summary of your data in some other program (Excel?), which makes me think there is probably a simpler solution to your problem if you simply load your raw data into R and calculate the average, mean, min and so forth in R, or if you summarize your data in that external program in a format more canonical to R. Not knowing exactly what that raw data looks like, I can't give you a better answer.

Much of ggplot is organized around a set of principles for how data ought to be organized: I recommend reading through [this blog post on dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) and [this one on tidyr](https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/).

Comment: Mmm.... I got a different output. What is your desired output? Can your draw it? What I'm displaying uses the exact code I'm showing you , with a file called `data.csv` containing the exact text as copied from your question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your comment. The code should work regardless of the original data size (there are at least 2 rows, because the first row are the column names, because of the way `t` screws up the format of the data frame). What do you mean by error check? Can you reproduce my output?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output. Can you please show what are your data structures before and after the transpose?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very concise version using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

# read data and transpose
transposed <- data.table::dcast(data.table::melt(fread("data2.csv"), id.vars = "Vars"), 
                                variable ~ ...)
setnames(transposed, "variable", "Vars")
# reshape to long for plotting
molten <- data.table::melt(transposed, measure.vars = c("Absolute", "Average"))
```

**Edit**: I've amended above code to use the double colon operator to explicitely state the namespace from which `melt()`and `dcast()` should be taken. Normally, this wouldn't be necessary as `data.table` is already loaded. However, the OP is reporting issues which might be caused by package `reshape2` being loaded after `data.table`. The `data.table` package has it's own faster implementations of `reshape2::dcast()` and `reshape2::melt()`. When both packages have been loaded for some reason name clashes might occur.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(molten, aes(Vars, value, fill = variable, ymin = Min, ymax = Max)) + 
  geom_col() + geom_errorbar(width = 0.2)
```

[image]

#### Data

I had to remove the `"` from the csv file. This was the fastest way to get rid of an error message from `fread()` complaining about the format of the header.  So, `data2.csv` looks like:

```
Vars    ,   Sleep,  Awake,    REM, Deep 
Absolute,        ,       , 5     , 7
Average , 7      , 12    ,       , 
Min     , 4      , 5     ,       , 
Max     , 10     , 15    ,       ,
```

Comment: Please try updated code. Something in your environment seems to be mixed up. For me, the code is working correctly. Perhaps, you need restart with a clean R session?

Comment: Thank you for providing output from `sessionInfo()`. As suspected in my edited answer, you have already loaded `reshape2` which could explain the issues. So, either try my edited code (which explicitely calls the `data.table`versions of `melt()` and `dcast()`) or try to avoid to load `reshape2`.

Comment: Please, show also the contents of the input file `test111.csv`.

Comment: I believe, I've solved the riddle: These are caused by the `"` in the data. As a workaround, please remove these from the input file and test again. I will later update the code in my answer appropriately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144993/discussion-between-uwe-block-and-leo-leopold-hertz-).

Answer (score 2):

I am approaching this a bit differently. If I take the original data as

```
> data
  Vars variable value
 Sleep Absolute  <NA>
 Awake Absolute  <NA>
   REM Absolute     5
  Deep Absolute     7
 Sleep  Average     7
 Awake  Average    12
   REM  Average  <NA>
  Deep  Average  <NA>
 Sleep      Min     4
 Awake      Min     5
   REM      Min  <NA>
  Deep      Min  <NA>
 Sleep      Max    10
 Awake      Max    15
   REM      Max  <NA>
  Deep      Max  <NA>
```

And convert the data to

```
minmax <- ds[ds$variable %in% c("Min","Max"), ]
absol  <- ds[ds$variable %in% c("Average", "Absolute"), ]
minm   <- dcast(minmax, Vars ~ variable)
absol <- merge(absol, minm, by = "Vars", all.x = T)
>absol

      Vars variable value Max Min
     Awake  Average    12  15   5
      Deep Absolute     7  NA  NA
       REM Absolute     5  NA  NA
     Sleep  Average     7  10   4
```

Then I can use `ggplot2`, then I can use

```
ggplot(absol, aes(x = Vars, y = value, fill = variable)) +
       geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
       geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Min, ymax = Max), width = .25)
```

which results in

[image]

Comment: I added a wiki answer here to show explicitly the data conversion for your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44097150/54964

Comment: I have to ask why? What is the data meant to look like? and why are there gaps? The gaps explained in this problem seemed to be about data type more than actual missing completely at random.

Comment: I am thinking how to use this `dat.m <- melt(as.data.table(dat.m, keep.rownames = "Vars"), id.vars = "Vars") # https://stackoverflow.com/a/44128640/54964` here instead of the manual conversion to the long table here. What do you think? I think this one line can really be useful here too.

Comment: It definitely can. And it will increase the efficiency.

Answer (score -1):

Completion of akash87's code because the data conversion is not explicit in his answer from the original dta set

```
library("ggplot2")

dat.m <- read.csv("data.csv", strip.white=TRUE)

m <- t(dat.m)
dat.m <- data.frame(m[2:nrow(m),])
names(dat.m) <- m[1,]
dat.m$Vars <- rownames(m)[2:nrow(m)]

library("reshape2")
dat.m <- melt(dat.m, id.vars="Vars")

ds <- dat.m
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/44090815/54964
minmax <- ds[ds$variable %in% c("Min","Max"), ]
absol  <- ds[ds$variable %in% c("Average", "Absolute"), ]
minm   <- dcast(minmax, Vars ~ variable)
absol <- merge(absol, minm, by = "Vars", all.x = T)

absol

ggplot(absol, aes(x = Vars, y = value, fill = variable)) +
       geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
       geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Min, ymax = Max), width = .25)
```

Output: same as in akash87's aswer.

Comment: I think the application of the following answer should be done also here when coverting to long table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44128640/54964