# How to ggplot partial values with only max in whisker plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am thinking how to present partial values in whisker plot/... 
`M2` has only the max. 
Both measurements do not hav
Code which output in Fig. 1

```
library("reshape2")
library("ggplot2")

ds <- structure(list(Vars = c("M1", "M2", "M1", "M2", "M1", "M2"), 
variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Max", 
"Ave", "Min"), class = "factor"), value = c("150", 
"61", " 60", NA, " 41", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("Vars", 
"variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")

# http://stackoverflow.com/q/44100187/54964 eipi10
ds$value = as.numeric(ds$value)

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/44090815/54964
minmax <- ds[ds$variable %in% c("Min","Max"), ]
absol  <- ds[ds$variable %in% c("Ave"), ]
# absol  <- ds[ds$variable %in% c("Ave", "Absolute"), ]
minm   <- dcast(minmax, Vars ~ variable)
absol  <- merge(absol, minm, by = "Vars", all.x = T)

absol

ggplot(absol, aes(x = Vars, y = value, fill = variable)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Min, ymax = Max), width = .25)
```

Values at start

```
            Max      Ave       Min Vars
M1          150       60        41   M1
M2           61     <NA>      <NA>   M2
```

Fig. 1 Output where no visualisations when only max value exists

[image]

The presentation of M1 is also weird in the barplot becuase no absolute values in data, designed initially in `absol`.

Expected output: mark maximum value in `M2` presentation

OS: Debian 8.7
R: 3.4 (backports)

Comment: `value` is a character variable in your data, so it's being treated as a factor in the plot. When you create `ds` don't put quotes around the numbers in `value`, so that `value` will be numeric. Or you can do `ds$value = as.numeric(ds$value)`.

Comment: @eipi10 I added the fix in the body. The y-axis looks now ok, but otherwise, the same situation persists. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column to `absol`, call it `yMin`, that will set the min value to the max value if the min value is missing.

```
absol$yMin <- ifelse(is.na(absol$Min), absol$Max, absol$Min)
```

Then, when plotting, have the `geom_errorbar` use `yMin` in the aesthetics.

```
ggplot(absol, aes(x = Vars, y = value, fill = variable)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = yMin, ymax = Max), width = .25)
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is the right answer to the question. I think the next step is to improve the initial data structure like done here https://stackoverflow.com/q/44030346/54964 I will be thinking about it soon.